# How can I deserialize data from xml and how can I create classes dynamically by xml element name?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a dynamic XML structure. I mean,  root name can be changed, element name can be changed and structure of xml can be changed.So How can I deserialize dynamic xml to objects?

Creating classes dynamically by xml element names, is this possible? If yes, then how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> So How can I deserialize this type xml to objects?

Well, you cannot deserialize a XML without a specific XSD schema to statically typed classes. You could use a [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) or [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) classes to parse and extract information from it.

Comment: XML is just text, it can be parsed without a schema and interpreted however you want. I seen many bad ways of doing it, some even used schemas. Schemas are useful for defining and verifying the structure of the XML.

Comment: @Skizz, of course that it can be parsed without a schema. I never said the contrary. What I said is that without a schema or something that defines statically what the structure of this XML file you cannot deserialize it to statically typed objects simply because if the XML contains nodes that are not defined in the static objects they won't be serialized. That's the reason why I suggested using `XDocument` which is like a static class but allows to handle any valid XML structure.

Comment: Thank you fow answer Darin, I solve xml binding to objects with string xmlFilePath = "cars.xml"; DataSet DSXml = new DataSet(); FileStream fsReadXml = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open); DSXml.ReadXml(fsReadXml); dataGridView1.DataSource = DSXml; this code but still I can not create class with xml element and root names

Comment: @Bilgehan, you can't because the structure of this XML is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .Net 4, the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28VS.100%29.aspx) might be what you need:

> Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time.

Comment: Thank you Stuart I will try ExpandoObject for create the dynamic classes wşth xml element names. by the way I solve xml binding to objects with string xmlFilePath = "cars.xml"; DataSet DSXml = new DataSet(); FileStream fsReadXml = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open); DSXml.ReadXml(fsReadXml); dataGridView1.DataSource = DSXml;

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). The basic idea is:

```
for each XML node, get the type name / name of node
  ask factory for type with given name
  create object of the given type
  pass the XML node to object to allow it to load its data
```

XSD schemas help here to verify the XML is structurally correct although not necessary. I did try this once, creating objects from XML, but I never found a way to have multiple schema files for one XML (this would have allowed me to extend the schema without changing the root schema, if you see what I mean).

Comment: Thank you fow answer Skizz, I solve xml binding to objects with 
string xmlFilePath = "cars.xml";
            DataSet DSXml = new DataSet();
            FileStream fsReadXml = new FileStream(xmlFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            DSXml.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DSXml;
this code but still I can not create class with xml element and root names